# app crash when seek use MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here is my problem, I tried to use **MPMoviePlayerController** to play stream video, so I prepare to put the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view in my custom viewController set the `controlStyle` property to *MPMovieControlStyleNone*, and I provide the custom player controller, and in my init method:

```
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];  
_moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;  
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
_moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;  
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

and I put custom player controll on the `moviePlayer`, when I prepare to play, I get the real URL from network and the let `moviePlayer` to play:

```
_moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];  
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

then I register the related notification to report what happening
I provide the simple seek method `seek` and just call the `moviePlayer`'s seek method, I found when the network latency is high and I try to seek,  after some times, the app crashed. and the following the call stack:

```
`0 CoreFoundation 0x381bd8a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186  
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x334ee259 objc_exception_throw + 32  
2 AVFoundation 0x37afb0dd -[AVPlayerItem _attachToPlayer:forImmediateEnqueueing:shouldAppendItem:] + 320   
3 AVFoundation 0x37af1edb -[AVPlayer _insertPlaybackItemOfItem:inPlayerQueueAfterPlaybackItemOfItem:] + 42  
4 AVFoundation 0x37af2c37 __block_global_0 + 1038  
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x34ae5c59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12  
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x34ae7ee7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 194
7 CoreFoundation  0x381902ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1268  
8   CoreFoundation  0x381134a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300  
9   CoreFoundation  0x3811336d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104  
10  GraphicsServices0x365f6439 GSEventRunModal + 136  
11  UIKit 0x30fc4cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080  
12  Player 0x000284dd main + 152  
13  Player 0x0001abb8 start + 40  
"Exception Name" = NSInvalidArgumentException  
"Exception Reason" = "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer`
```

See the expection reason, I guess may I init muti instance of AVPlayer, but I only have one MPMoviePlayerController, and can any one point me the direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any of your code so it's impossible to make sense of your question. The problem is something *you* are doing wrong, so you must show exactly what *you* are doing if you want help.

However, please note that Apple may be already helping you. The error message you're getting is very explicit:

> "Exception Reason" = "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

That could be a huge clue. It could be useful to think about how you might be violating that rule.

Comment: hi, I add the code, and I want to know the relationship between the AVPlayerItem and MPMoviePlayerController, thanks for your answer.